# Unity C# error 'cs0116' "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new at C# scripting and the whole Unity thing.

I've watched tutorials and read a dozen forums from users that got the same error and I've tried to fix it
but I feel like I'm messing it up more.

Unity is saying the error is on line 16 column 10, visual study can't pick up any errors.
It was meant to be a simple script to make my character move but it's getting real difficult to solve whatever is happening.

What Unity is saying :

https://ibb.co/sbF2SPK

My script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(int mDir)
    { }
    private float speed = 2.0f;
    public GameObject character;
}


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    forward;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: The update Method need to be inside the NewBehaviourScript brackets

Comment: Also refer to this similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235340/error-cs0116-a-namespace-cannot-directly-contain-members-such-as-fields-or-meth

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235340/error-cs0116-a-namespace-cannot-directly-contain-members-such-as-fields-or-meth)

Comment: Looks like a typo `}` after `public GameObject character;`

Answer (score 1):

All members (field, property and method) have to be in a class. In your case, the method `Update` isn't in a class. Maybe you close the class `NewBehaviourScript` too early. More information in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes).

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start(int mDir)
        {
        }

        private float speed = 2.0f;
        public GameObject character;

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            forward;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                transform.position += Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    } // Close the class NewBehaviourScript
} // Close the namespace
```

Little advice, you can also encapsulate the class in namespace classify classes. Generally, the namespace name is the project'name + folder structure.